# Android: Ellipsize the text of a key in the Soft Keyboard IME

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, ime

```
In normal textview etc we can ellipsize the text by command:  
android:ellipsize=""

I am customizing the android's soft keyboard. I want to know that is their a way to ellipsize the key of keyboard?

My code is:

<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:horizontalGap="1px"
    android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:verticalGap="-5%p" >

    <!-- android:verticalGap="@dimen/verticalGap" > -->

    <Row>
        <Key
            android:codes="555555"
            android:horizontalGap="1.5%p"
            android:isRepeatable="true"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
            android:keyHeight="@dimen/mic_key_height"
            android:keyIcon="@drawable/voice_input"
            android:keyWidth="28.5%p" />
        <Key
            android:codes="111111"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:horizontalGap="2%p"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:keyHeight="@dimen/templates_key_height"
            android:keyWidth="67%p" />
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key
            android:codes="222222"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:horizontalGap="32%p"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:keyHeight="@dimen/templates_key_height"
            android:keyWidth="67%p" />
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key
            android:codes="333333"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:horizontalGap="32%p"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:keyHeight="@dimen/templates_key_height"
            android:keyWidth="67%p" />
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key
            android:codes="777777"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:horizontalGap="32%p"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:keyHeight="@dimen/templates_key_height"
            android:keyWidth="67%p" />
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key
            android:codes="666666"
            android:horizontalGap="1.5%p"
            android:isModifier="true"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
            android:keyHeight="@dimen/templates_key_height"
            android:keyIcon="@drawable/voice_keyboard_enable"
            android:keyWidth="28.5%p"
            android:verticalGap="1.5%p" />
        <Key
            android:codes="444444"
            android:horizontalGap="1.7%p"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:keyHeight="@dimen/templates_key_height"
            android:keyLabel="@string/more_templates"
            android:keyWidth="67%p"
            android:verticalGap="1%p" />
    </Row>

</Keyboard>
```

I am customizing the android's soft keyboard. I want to know that is their a way to ellipsize the key of keyboard? I am adding the text to the keys dynamically but the text flows out of the key boundaries.
I want to ellipsize the key.

Comment: Help me.. If the question is incomplete or some info is missing please let me know.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot ellipsize because it has the label, not the text.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a easy way, but you can create images for each key in the way you want them to be, then you put in your keyboard with:

```
android:keyIcon=""
```